# STL container holding class within declaration of that class

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, stl

I have written a program in C++ that compiles with clang++ but not with g++ and I would like to understand why.

The essential part is this:

```
class Table {
    private:
        ...
        std::unordered_map<std::string,Table> table_map;
        ...
};
```

I thought that std::unordered_map would be using pointers "under the hood", so that this is legal.  I'm not declaring a Table inside of a Table, but I'm creating a container that has pointer(s) to Table(s) inside of a Table.  Or so I thought.  Clang++ has no problem with this and the program runs fine.

However, g++ complains about this, saying "`note: forward declaration of 'class Table'`".  This suggests I should explicitly make the std::unordered_map take a pointer (`std::unordered_map<std::string,Table*>`, or perhaps some flavor of smart pointer).  That requires I do some extra work (and I'm dealing with code I wrote over a year ago, so I'm not eager to have to figure out what I did in order to make the necessary changes).

Is this a bug in g++ or is clang++ doing something clever that's not really part of the standard?  Is there a better way to rewrite this code so that it compiles on both clang++ and g++?

I have another class called Value, and there's a std::unordered_map of Values within Table, so would I get around this problem by creating a superclass Element from which Value and Table both inherit, and then having Table contain a `std::unordered_map<std::string,Element>`?  Or would such a map be unable to store Values and Tables because it was declared for Elements?

Comment: There are plans for `std::vector`, std::list`, and `std::forward_list` to support incomplete types, but not `std::unordered_map` yet. Perhaps Boost's map supports it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is caused by std::unordered_map having to rehash the table and then copying of elements. The value stored in container must therefore be a complete type.

You can get over it by wrapping value into smart pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>           // shared_ptr

class Table {
    private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Table> > t;
};

int main() {
    Table t;
    return 0;
}
```

[Compiles](https://ideone.com/taQ7H1).

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behaviour. Standard library containers may not be instantiated with incomplete types, unless it explicitly says that the container supports it (e.g. `unique_ptr`).

Your options are:

- Redesign your code to not do this
- Use a container library that does support this